# How to test a method returns boolean in Mockito

Tags: android, junit, mockito, junit4, powermockito

I am learning how to unit-testing in android studio. As shown below, I have a method called "isValidUrl" and in the testing section below, I coded the testing
of that method using Mockito, but the test always fails.

Can you please help and guild me how to test this method?

**code**

```
public boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
    return (url != null && !url.equals("")) ? true : false;
}
```

**testing**:

```
public class ValidationTest {
@Mock
private Context mCtx = null;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mCtx = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull("Context is not null", mCtx);
}

@Test
public void isValidUrl() throws Exception {
    Validation validation = new Validation(mCtx);
    String url = null;
    Mockito.when(validation.isValidUrl(url)).thenReturn(false);
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting an exception because you're trying to mock the behaviour of a 'real' object (`validation`).

You need to separate two things: **mocking** and **asserting**.

**Mocking** means creating 'fake' objects of a class (like you did with `Context`) and defining their behaviour before the test. 
In your case

```
 Mockito.when(validation.isValidUrl(url)).thenReturn(false);
```

means, you tell the `validation` object to returns false if `isValidUrl(url)` is called. You can only do that with mocked objects though, and in your case there's no point in doing that anyway, because you want to test the 'real' behaviour of your `Validation` class, not the behaviour of a mocked object. 
Mocking methods is usually used to define the behaviour of the dependencies of the class, in this case, again, the `Context`. 
For your test right here, this will not be necessary.

**Asserting** then does the actual 'test' of how the class under test should behave.

You want to test that `isValid()` return false for an `url` that is `null`:

```
Assert.assertEquals(validation.isValid(null), false);
```

or shorter:

```
Assert.assertFalse(validation.isValid(null));
```

You can use `assertEquals`, `assertFalse`, `assertTrue` and [some others](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Assertions) to verify that your `isValid()` method returns what you want it to return for a given `url` parameter.

Comment: thank you for your answer..but can i use more than one Assert in the same method..because i want to test isValid(null), isValid(true) and isValid(false)

Comment: @user2121 Yes you can. It's a matter of taste, most people would recommend you to do an extra test method for each of those cases, but you can also do as many assertions as you like in one test method.

Comment: thanks..i posted another question related to testing here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262467/how-to-test-picasso-using-unit-test-and-mockito     maybe you want to have a look, and your answer will be a guiding line for me and as a tutorial as well because i am learning testing units