# how to test picasso using unit-test and mockito

Tags: android, junit, mocking, mockito, junit4

I am learning how to unit-testing in android studio. as shown below, I would like to test the two methods shown below in the code section.

can you please help and guide me how to test this method?

**code**

```
public RequestCreator requestCreatorFromUrl(String mPicUrl) 
{
    return Picasso.with(mCtx).load(mPicUrl);
}

public void setImageOnImageView(RequestCreator requestCreator, ImageView mImagView) 
{
    requestCreator.into(mImagView);
}
```

**My Attempts**:

```
@Test
public void whenRequestCreatorFromUrlTest() throws Exception {
    Picasso mockPicasso = mock(Picasso.class);
    File mockFile = mock(File.class);

    Assert.assertNotNull("returned Request creator is not null",    
 mockPicasso.load(mockFile));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First method you can't test, you'd have to verify the call of a static method which is not supported in Mockito. 
You could split the method in

```
public RequestCreator requestCreator() {
    return Picasso.with(mCtx); 
}
```

and

```
public void load(RequestCreator requestCreator, String picUrl) {
   requestCreator.load(picUrl)
}
```

and test the `load(...)` method.

Second method:

Mock the `requestCreator`. Mock the `imageView`. 
Call the method with your mocked objects. 
Then verify `requestCreator.into(...)` was called with the supplied parameter:

```
Mockito.verify(requestCreator).into(imageView);
```

Comment: i tried to ttest load methods as follows:public void whenRequestCreatorFromUrl() throws Exception {
        ImageView mockedImageView = Mock (ImageView.class);
        RequestCreator requestCreator = Mock (new RequestCreator.class);
    }  but i receive errors..would you please help me

Comment: i am trying to test load method as you stated it in your answer, but .load() method is not a property of requestCreator object??!!

Comment: Check what with(context) returns and use that.

Comment: .load() method is  aproperty of Picasso object so i did the follwoing to mock Picasso object:public void whenRequestCreatorFromUrlTest() throws Exception {
        Picasso mockPicasso = Mock(Picasso.with(mCtx));
    }   but it does it work

Comment: @user2121Picasso mockPicasso = Mock(Picasso.class); just like the other object you mocked.